# Разница между коллекциями

Tags: c#, коллекции

Товарищи, нужно просветление!

Есть 3 коллекции типа словаря. Это `Dictionary <Key, Value>`, `SortedDictionary <Key, Value>`, `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`. Разницу между последними 2-мя я вообще не понял. Но еще не разберусь, каким образом хранятся и сортируются элементы в `Dictionary <Key, Value>` написано, что сортировка элементов в данной коллекции идет по хешу ключа. Однако почему-то в этом коде элементы выводятся в той последовательности, в которой я их ввел:

```
static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        dict.Add("Gleb", 2);
        dict.Add("Pavel", 6);
        dict.Add("Anna", 4);
        dict.Add("Sergey", 3);
        foreach (var v in dict.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v);
        }
    }
```

Ведь, по идее, они должны быть в псевдослучайном порядке. Почему тогда так происходит? И какая разница между `SortedDictionary <Key, Value>` и `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`?

[image]

Comment: >каким образом хранятся и сортируются элементы в Dictionary <Key, Value> 

эммм..ну вообще они никак не сортируются - для этого существует SortedDictionary, очевидно же

>Ведь по идее они должны быть в псевдослучайном порядке

почему это они должны? То есть, как вы себе это представляете? Вы добавляете данные в Dictionary, а их там по какому-то алгоритму случайно тасуют будто карты в колоде? Напрашивается вопрос - зачем?

Comment: Прикрепил к своему вопросу картинку.

Comment: Откуда картинка? :)

Comment: К сожелению, текст не выделялся, поэтому пришлось картинку лепить

Comment: https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=jWUaBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA264&lpg=PA264&dq=c%23+dictionary+tkey+tvalue&source=bl&ots=nSgn24inID&sig=D6uL9-3TqN_5nBToW8q35lm3aKI&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=v-kCVZPkHIGjyAO0tYCAAg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=c%23%20dictionary%20tkey%20tvalue&f=false

Comment: http://s020.radikal.ru/i708/1406/e1/5868c87a4458.jpg В шилдте наткнулся, что действительно Dictionary не сортируется!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. При итерации по `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` элементы возвращаются в том порядке, в котором были добавлены по той причине, что внутри себя `Dictionary` содержит список `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` (говорю очень грубо и с допущениями). Этот список и возвращается, когда вы юзаете foreach.

Касательно второго вопроса:

1. SortedList<TKey, TValue> использует меньше памяти, чем SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>.
2. В SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> быстрее вставлять и удалять неупорядоченные данные
3. Если список заполнять отсортированными данными, то SortedList <TKey, TValue> быстрее, чем SortedDictionary <TKey, TValue>.